# how to deal with dates 6 months ahead if year increments

Tags: javascript, date

Here is my function, I am trying to get the date 6 months ahea, or 6 months before.

```
  var newEndDate = formatDateaddMonths(startDate,+6);

 function formatDateaddMonths(dateMod, monthsAddedDeducted)
       {

           //startDate
           //split date
           var dateSplit = dateMod;
           var dateSplitted = dateSplit.split("/");
           var day = dateSplitted[0];
           var month = dateSplitted[1];
           var year = dateSplitted[2];

           console.log("day" + day);
           console.log("month" + month);
           console.log("year" + year);

           newDateModification = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
           var newDate = Date.parse(newDateModification).add(monthsAddedDeducted).months();
           //convert to string
           var newDateString = newDate.toString('dd/MM/yyyy');
           return newDateString;
       }
```

This works fine as long as the function is not called before the end of the year.

It breaks for example if the `startDate = 10/11/2015` because the year is not incremented, with the date end up being `29/12/2015`

```
Date.parse(newDateModification).add(monthsAddedDeducted).months();
```

is a date.js function

Any idea how to deal with year increments?

Thanks.

Comment: You should increment and decrement the date values in milliseconds, that way it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function similar to

```
normalizeMonths( dateString ){
    var split = dateString.split("/");
    if ( split[1] > 12 ){
        split[1] = split[1] - 12;
        split[2] = split[2] + 1;
    }
```

and then reassemble the date like you did before, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use moment.js:

```
var a = moment([2010, 0, 31]).subtract(6, 'months');
var b = moment([2010, 0, 31]).add(6, 'months');
```